# Gerar um iframe apartir do link do youtube com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

Gostaria de gerar um iframe do youtube que retornarei para uma div assim que o usuário colar o link do video em um campo, sei criar com php, mais gostaria de fazer com jquery, assim já retorno para a div sem precisar de ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
var linkYoutube = //link do YouTube.
var $iframe = $('<iframe/'>).attr('src', linkYoutube);
$('ID_DIV').append($iframe);
```

Comment: não funcionou, ele gera o iframe, mais sem o video

Comment: Eu ajustei minha resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a resposta:

```
function getId(url) {
        var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
        var match = url.match(regExp);

        if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
            return match[2];
        } else {
            return 'error';
        }
    }

    var myId = getId('link_do_video');

    $('#myId').html(myId);

    $('#myCode').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' + myId + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponha que queremos mostrar o seguinte vídeo do **YouTube**, dentro de um `iframe`:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[id_do_video]

Para isso devemos converter ele para:

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/[id_do_video]

E depois passar essa `url` para o `src` do `iframe`:

```js
function goYoutube() {
  var link = document.getElementById('link');
  var iframe = document.getElementById('youtube');
  
  // Busca o "ID" do vídeo
  var id = link.value.split('watch?v=')[1];

  // Verifica se obteve um "ID"
  if(!id) {
    alert("Link está incorreto!");
    return;
  }
  
  // Seta o src do iframe para a url convertida
  iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + id;
}
```

```html
<label for="link">Digite o link aqui</label>
<input type="text" id="link" onblur="goYoutube()">

<br>
<br>

<iframe id="youtube" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```